# What is the Benice equation?

Tags: systems-of-equations, circles, parametric, osculating-circle

I keep seeing lots & lots of pictures generated by the Benice equation (usually spirograph type things or fractal like things) but nowhere have I seen a reference or an explicit explaination of what the Benice equation actually is.

So I'm asking here, what is the Benice equation?

My assumption is that they are parametric equations of some sort to do with rotating circles.

If possible please supply references.

[image: Fractal tree generated by Benice equation]

[image]

Comment: I'm starting to think you might be right